# Syntax error while creating a trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a table name **Student** in PostgreSQL and then I tried defining a trigger on that table but it's showing an error message in doing so.

Trigger Syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_Student BEFORE INSERT ON Student as $$ 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    raise notice 'Successfully inserted into table(%)', user;   
end $$;
```

Table Creation Command:

```
create table Student(Stu_id int, Stu_Name text, Stu_Age int, Stu_address char(30));
```

Actually I tried to declare the execution statements directly inside the trigger only rather than calling any procedure/ function from the trigger which is working fine but I want to do in this way in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that syntax?

Comment: No in the manual I did not find that

Comment: So why do you think it's valid?

Comment: That was my question. :)

Comment: The structure of your trigger is for Oracle. As others have shown Postgres trigger must call a function/procedure.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't support it. You need trigger function always.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you help me with one more doubt I have?
I tried moving my execution statements inside a trigger function which returns a trigger 

create function MB_MDDeleteMDLibraryPGSQL()returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ 
declare
 integer_var bigint;
begin
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT; 
if ROW_COUNT = 0 then 
   return ;
end if;
delete from MB_MDFieldProps where MB_MDFieldProps.propId = OLD.col1;
end $$;
as you can see here I have to use the return keyword under "if" but I am not returning any value as per my requirement but it's showing an error.

Comment: @SugataKar - this code has not sense. Using GET DIAGNOSTICS in trigger is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) you need a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

```
create function my_trigger_function()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  raise notice 'Successfully inserted into table(%)', user;   
  return new; --<< important (see the manual for details)
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Not sure what you intend with the `user` parameter there, as that is not the table name, but the current database user. If you want to display the actual table name, you need to use `TG_RELNAME` instead - which is an [implicit variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) available in the trigger function.

And a [trigger definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_Student 
BEFORE INSERT ON Student 
FOR EACH ROW
execute function my_trigger_function();
```